# How to put an value to the extracting JSON and display it

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I wanna display a parsed json with my values . I mean , I wanna add some values to the json and  display it . I can display all result from respond , but I wanna display just the json with my values not all data :)

here i have parsed allready my json

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(adresUrl);

```
            JSONArray offerResources = jsonObject.getJSONArray("offerResources");
            for(int y =  0; y < offerResources.length(); y++){
                JSONObject currentTransfer = offerResources.getJSONObject(y);

                JSONArray meetPoint = currentTransfer.getJSONArray("meetPoints");
                for (int i = 0; i < meetPoint.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject currentMeetPoints = meetPoint.getJSONObject(i);

                    String startAddress = currentMeetPoints.getString("startAddress"); // here i wanna put some values , but i dont know how
```

// here is a  litle piece of my json :)

```
  "meetPoints": [
    {
      "startAddress": "....", // after the collon i have to put my value .
      "startLocation": {
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question fully but from what I got here is some solution. I simply created a string and couple of Json objects and jsonarray for adding the list of values and put it inside the main json object "jsonValueObject " and accumulate it inside meetPoints.

Accumulate(String key,Object Value) is a key value pair, meaning if key is created then Object is checked for being an array,and if this array has "values", it will be added else new array will be created. "Put" will replace the value if the key exists.

```
String jsonString = "{\"results\":[{\"Country\":\"value\",\"state\":\"value\" }, 
{ \"Country\":\"value\", \"state\":\"value\"}]}";


JSONObject meetPoints = new JSONObject(jsonDataString);
JSONObject jsonValueObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
jsonValueObject.put("Country", "newValue");
jsonValueObject.put("state", "newValue");
jsonValueObject.put("city", "Chennai");
jsonValueObject.put("street", "Bharathiyar Street");
jsonValueObject.put("date", "14May2017");
jsonValueObject.put("time", "10:00AM");
list.put(jsonValueObject);
meetPoints.accumulate("values", list);
System.out.println(meetPoints);
```